# Iphone and Facebook Connect?

Tags: iphone, fbconnect

Does anybody know if you can actually pull done messages/comments from facebook into an iPhone app? Every app I see in the app store allows you to post to facebook. I have an app idea that includes actually seeing your friends messages and wanted to see if the SO community has seen anything like this before or if you are able to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do this; FBConnect lets you call all of the Facebook APIs, so you'd want to look at http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.get or http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Comments.get.  I haven't done anything with comments directly, but I do have an app that retrieves lists of friends, photo albums, and photos on the iPhone using FBConnect so I think this would be very similar, and it wasn't that hard to do.